# Increase plot resolution in Quarto book using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, quarto

When rendering a book in R, Quarto saves the plot images generated in each chapter within the `./chapter_name/figure-html` directories. By default, images are saved with a resolution that is good enough for online book websites, but not good enough for printing.

Is there a way to, at least temporarily, generate all ggplots in higher resolution so we can send them to production to print the book ?

ps. [The Quarto documentation is great, but they don't mention any info om plot resolutions on their page](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html).

Comment: Does setting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dpi = 300)` in the beginning not help?

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#figures. The `fig-dpi` option is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

As @tarleb mentioned, setting `fig-dpi` in the YAML format options is one solution. However, the `ggsave()` default is already 300, so for printing, 600 might be preferred.

Nonetheless, even better would be using lossless vector graphics. The Quarto PDF Format uses `.pdf` for figures by default. But that usually doesn't work well with HTML. However, you could set `fig-format` to `svg`.

```
format:
  html: 
    fig-format: svg
```

https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/html#figures